# What's -> and . in linkedlists?

Tags: c

I'm working with linked lists in C. Can someone please explain the function and purpose of:

```
t->next;
```

and

```
t.next;
```

Comment: Do you know what pointers are? If yes: `a->b` is syntactic sugar for `(*a).b`. So the `->` dereferences a pointer first, while `.` itself doesn't. `t.next` makes sense if `t` is a struct or class (`MyClass t`), `t->next` makes sense if `t` is a **pointer** to a struct/class (`MyClass* t`). If you don't know what pointers are: Please learn about them first, otherwise none of the explanations will make sense to you.

Comment: A C tutorial and book might be a good place to start: a_struct_pointer->member vs a_struct.member

Comment: What si `t` ? Both fragments assume a different definition...

Answer (score 0):

To access the member of the `struct` or `union` the `.` is used. To dereference pointer to the `struct` or `union` and access the member `->` is used as in he examples blelow

```
struct node
{
    struct node *next;
};


void foo()
{
    struct node n;
    struct node *np = &n;
     
    // accessing member of the struct 
    n.next = &n;
    // accessing member of the struct via the pointer
    np -> next = &n;

    // accessing member of the struct via the derefenced pointer
    (*np).next = &n;

    (&n) -> next = &n;
}
```